# Why is my link field not aliasing my path when the link is for the current node?

Tags: 7, navigation, nodes

I have a content type that includes a link field using the [Link module](https://drupal.org/project/link). That content type is used to create nodes that will be displayed on a Basic Page using the [Nodeblock module](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock); I'm using them as navigation elements.

When I have a nodeblock with "about-us/careers" in the link field, when I'm on the "about-us" page the link in that node block correctly displays and takes me to "http://example.com/about-us/careers", but when I show that same nodeblock on the "about-us/careers" page the link is displayed as "node/id".

The link is being output in a custom tpl file using the [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function and the safe_value.

Has anyone else experienced this and do you know what's causing it and therefore how to fix it?

Comment: "using the l() function" - why haven't you tried simply to render a field, instead of outputting it's content? Also, please don't link to commercial sites if they are not the ones you ask about ;) and include relevant parts of code, in this case your tpl file.

Comment: Hahaha sorry I didn't even realize that mydomain.com was a valid site. I'm using the l() function because I'm modifying the text value for the link based on certain conditions. Seems like a bug to me. I solved it by throwing the $base_url in from if the link value is internal...